# Designing Crystal Reports issue

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

[image: Crystal report Design]

> I need to design a crystal report in the above format as there are multiple "sqauad check" numbers and for each of those number there are multiple document details to be shown.how can i do
>   this with multiple detail sections? or do i have to use sub
>   reports.please give me an idea

Comment: looks like you just want to group by the squad-check-no?

Comment: yes.can i achieve this with two detail sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert groupings into crystal reports - I don't know your data-source so it's hard to tell but the picture looks like you have just to insert a group for the squad-check-no and use one detail to show the DocumentNumber, Document Titel, etc.

Comment: Groups look like the way to go if you group by squad number. The group header can be formatted with the squad number (assuming the grey bar in the sample) and you can specify the order of squad numbers in the edit group dialog.